# PDF comparison tool

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, diff, comparison

I want to compare two PDF files and show the differences.

The application must

- be gratis
- run on Windows (10 at least, 7 appreciated)
- compare the text that is contained in those PDFs
- visually highlight the changes found

I don't need

- comparison of the images contained in the PDF

I don't want

- visual comparison, such as using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [pyPdfCompare](https://github.com/kspeeckaert/pyPdfCompare)(which were suggested in one of the linked answers)
- trials or free versions that can open PDFs limited in size, such as [DiffNow](https://www.diffnow.com/) (which was suggested in one of the linked answers). I have documents that are 20 MB or larger.

The PDFs in question are in general similar with respect to text. I expect only little changes. However, visual comparison is not possible, since adding a sentence may move all subsequent content to a new page.

I have tried:

- copy/pasting the text of the PDF and using a Diff-Tool like Winmerge. However, that resulted in issues with special characters such as `ß` and also with line breaks. Also, in the end it's hard to find out on which page that difference is.
- the question [Free PDF comparison tool](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17018/free-pdf-comparison-tool), but it has been asked for OS X and I need it for Windows. I have tried some of the tools that work on Windows as well,

Answer (score 2):

## [diffpdf](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/diffpdf_portable) (version 2)

`diffpdf` is premium software from version 3 onward, but version 2 is still gratis.

- Gratis
- Runs on Windows
- Compare PDFs side-by-side in a GUI with highlighting
- Synchronized scrolling
- Portable app - no installation required

Available at https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/diffpdf_portable

[image: Screenshot of diffpdf comparing two files and highlighting changes in pink]

Note: Diffpdf compares the PDFs page-by-page, so it won't work as well if the changes have moved a paragraph to a different page. There's a couple ways to work around this:

1. You can specify which pairs of pages to compare. For example, if a paragraph has moved from page 2 to page 3 in the new version of the file, compare page 2 with page 3 in order to compare that paragraph.

[image: Shows comparing page 4 of one document to page 5 of a different document]

2. You can use [this bash script](https://askubuntu.com/a/297285/) to convert both PDFs to a single-page "scroll" before comparing them. (You can run bash scripts on Windows 10 using [wsl.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10))

Answer (score 1):

What about [diffpdf](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/PDF/DiffPDF.shtml) It uses text highlighting and runs on both windows and linux environment.

From softpedia:

> Differences between the two PDF items can be noticed by viewing their
>   content, since they are highlighted in red, according to the
>   comparison type of your choosing.

But I am not fully sure that it is completly gratis.

Comment: Sorry, it's not gratis, it just has a 20 days trial period.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently adding pdf support to my diff.  Its not free but fairly cheap at $19.  I have it working with some test pdf's but if you want to try it with your pdf's please contact the support email on my site and I can make it available to you.  See [AJC Diff](https://www.ajcsoft.com/diff-compare-files.htm)